# wordpress url rewriting for custom template

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am very new to wordpress and getting so confused that how to create custom url rewriting for   wordpress custom template. I have also try to find out it on google but no luck. I can't find proper solution for this.

Here is my current url structure:

```
http://example.com/chiptuning/search/?brand=Audi
```

using custom url rewriting I want to convert it to

```
http://example.com/chiptuning/search/brand/audi
```

or it may be

```
http://example.com/chiptuning/search/Audi
```

Please also mention where to put code.

**UPDATE**

The answer provided by @Mike Lewis is already used by me but it doesn't provide what I am looking for, anyway thanks for reply @Mike Lewis.

Any one else have any suggestion for the question? I need it fast, please.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress does its own magic for finding which template file to use.  If you know about rewrite rules, you can look through these pages:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

OR, here are a few simpler solutions:

**Using Hierarchical Pages**

site.com/page1/sub-page/sub-page/

You must add the pages using a browser through /wp-admin/, where you can then set its parent page.  You may also choose a specific template (PHP theme file) to use (see: [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and scroll down to Custom Page Templates).

**Use Hierarchical Categories**

You could also use hierarchical categories to tag posts, and then list them on the category archive pages.  For example:

You could have site.com/category/brand/audi/ (note, you can change the 'category' base part of this url in the wordpress settings).

You can create template files for the various tag archive pages:  category-brand.php would load for the `site.com/category/brand/` url, and category-audi.php would load for the `site.com/category/brand/audi/` url.

Note:  Depending on how dynamic your site needs to be, you may need to skip using a category-{tag}.php, so that it falls through to a generic category.php.  In this case, I believe both of the above urls would use the generic category.php (in the absence of a more specific template file - [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) scroll down to see the template hierarchy diagram).

This would prevent you from having to create a separate file for each individual tag.  Use the get_query_var() method to get the specific category tag.

**Last but not least**

If you're still stumped, there's another way to slice and dice the urls, without using rewrite rules.  BuddyPress (a plugin for wordpress) has a function that chops the url into pieces (/one/two/three/) and then uses these within PHP.  I'm not sure exactly how this works, but if you wanted to take a look, you can google/download BuddyPress, and look in the `buddypress/bp-core/bp-core-catchuri.php` file.

Here's the doc block:

```
/**
 * Analyzes the URI structure and breaks it down into parts for use in code.
 * BuddyPress can use complete custom friendly URI's without the user having to
 * add new re-write rules. Custom components are able to use their own custom
 * URI structures with very little work.
 *
 * @package BuddyPress Core
 * @since BuddyPress (1.0)
 *
 * The URI's are broken down as follows:
 *   - http:// domain.com / members / andy / [current_component] / [current_action] / [action_variables] / [action_variables] / ...
 *   - OUTSIDE ROOT: http:// domain.com / sites / buddypress / members / andy / [current_component] / [current_action] / [action_variables] / [action_variables] / ...
 *
 *  Example:
 *    - http://domain.com/members/andy/profile/edit/group/5/
 *    - $bp->current_component: string 'xprofile'
 *    - $bp->current_action: string 'edit'
 *    - $bp->action_variables: array ['group', 5]
 *
 */
function bp_core_set_uri_globals() {
```

Comment: This plugin is already used by me and no luck with it :( Do you have any other Idea or other suggestion? Please I need it fast :)